# Is there a way to return a 503 using azure application gateway

Tags: azure, redirect, http-status-code-503, azure-application-gateway

As the title says we are using azure application gateway to front all the traffic to our application. We want the ability to switch it into what will essentially be a maintenance mode and would like to return a 503 as opposed to the standard 502 it returns by default. We have a site [Here](http://maintenancesite.azurewebsites.net/) which simply returns a 503 and the idea would be to switch to a backend pool that contains this site, in the rule. However after setting this up we just get the standard 502 error. Is there a better way to go about this or some step I may be missing?

I have also tried configuring a redirect on the rule however this keeps any part of the url after the fqdn eg: "api.example.me/monitor/this" will turn into "maintenancesite.azurewebsites.net/monitor/this" and as such give a 404 instead

Comment: Hello, are you referring to Azure Application gateway redirect ?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Niz01Bf.png is the redirect i refer to in my second paragraph @ZahidFaroq It seems as if when the application gateway hits any sort of error page it returns a 502 instead of passing the error through

Comment: Check this link for error details on 502 AG https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502

Comment: A feature to configure custom error pages is under works. You should look out for when it is released.